# Getting modified dom content with query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML `div` layer with form input elements inside. I can get original content with `jQuery('#div').html()`, but when I modify form inputs, put text on input field and tick checkboxes, modification of the elements are not visible on `jQuery('#div').html()`. It will give only the content that was present when loading the page. So how it is possible to get HTML from the modified DOM instead referring to the page HTML structure?

Comment: You can't, because changing those things modifies _properties_ of the elements, not _attributes_. You'd have to check individual form elements to get their values and states.

Comment: use `$('form').serializeArray()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#div #your_input_name').value
```

`html` is the structure, `value` is the actual data in your input

or if you want the whole structure WITH data, use `innerHTML`